# Clearing spam/offensive flags shouldn't undelete a post deleted by Moderators or the post's owner

Tags: bug, spam, moderator-tools

When a mod "clears" the spam/offensive flags on a post the post gets undeleted. This is by design and made clear in the UI:

> Deletes all offensive and spam flags on this post, as well as any automatic Community downvotes. **If this post reached the flag limit, it will be undeleted and unlocked, and the owner will have their rep restored.**

(my bold)

However, [I had a case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36910487/59303) where a user posted an answer which got flagged as spam. Before it could get any more flags or a moderator could intervene the user deleted the answer. The spam flag remained (quite rightly) so mods can double check.

I decided that it wasn't really spam but I could see why someone thought it was so I wanted to clear the flag rather than decline it or mark it as helpful. Unfortunately this undeleted the answer so I had to delete it again. This is despite the option stating that it will only undelete when the post had reached the flag limit. One or two flags being cleared is not the flag limit.

Can the option work as advertised and not undelete posts that were deleted by direct user action rather than through the action of flags.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Meta SE rather? It seems like this bug would not only affect StackOverflow

Comment: @Magisch - possibly, but I encountered the bug here and it's perfectly OK to report bugs on child metas.

Comment: Mhm, fair enough

Comment: Had the same issue today; Deleted post, cleared single spam flag; post was auto-undeleted.  "If this post reached the flag limit" is a misnomer. 1 spam flag being cleared is not a flag limit.

Comment: Just my 2p. Maybe change the text to "this will change all spam or rude/abusive flags to disputed" - which is what it does rather than "delete" and remove the auto-undelete behaviour. While I might disagree with the flags on the post it doesn't mean the post itself shouldn't stay deleted. I just think an explicit undelete (if required) is better than an implicit undelete followed by an explicit delete.